# Facing Issue in migrating i686-linux-android-g++ Arch to x86_64-linux-android-g++ with android-ndk20 in native c++

Tags: android, c++, sdk, android-ndk, native

As per google's new announcement for mobile apps to Support 64 bit architecture to upload or update the App to Google Playstore, I started working on it by changing the native c++ SDK to support x86_64 bit architecture.
 I am getting an errors when using the 64bit compiler.

I am getting an ambiguous error when calling this code NeedWriteJson(int64_t int64Val) and apart from this i am getting another error with respect to the same scenario which i have mentioned below(Error 2)

I am using this compiler options for 32 bit compilation:

/usr/local/android-x86toolchain/bin/i686-linux-android-g++

Is there any compiler flags i have to add to support this changed? since i have to change in more number of places with respect to memory.

**My Compiler Options**

/usr/local/android-toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-g++  -DANDROID -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../include -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../include/core/external/aes -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../include/core/external/md5 -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../include/core/external/rapidjson -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../include/core/external/sqlite -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../include/core/external/sqliteCpp -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../../External/libs/android/include -I/Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/shared/../../External/libs/android/include/openssl -isystem /usr/local/android-x86toolchain/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /usr/local/android-x86toolchain/include/c++/4.8 -isystem /usr/local/android-x86toolchain/include/c++/4.8/i686-linux-android -fpic --sysroot=/usr/local/android-x86toolchain/sysroot -funwind-tables -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -pipe -fno-inline -fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types -std=c++11 -pthread -fPIC -frtti -fexceptions  -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -DANDROID -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DUSE_OPENSSL -DUSE_SSLEAY -DCURL_STATICLIB -D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1 -D_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -O2 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -MD -MT  MyMobileApp/wrapper/Android/build/student/jni/jniStudent.cpp.o -MF MyMobileApp/wrapper/Android/build/student/jni/jniStudent.cpp.o.d -o MyMobileApp/wrapper/Android/build/student/jni/jniStudent.cpp.o -c /Users/vishnu/MyProject/MyMobileApp/wrapper/Android/build/student/jni/jniStudent.cpp

**For 64 bit compilation:**

/usr/local/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++.

Since we dont need to create a standalone toolchain its using clang++.

```
     virtual bool NeedWriteJson(bool boolVal) = 0;
    virtual bool NeedWriteJson(int32_t int32Val) = 0;
    virtual bool NeedWriteJson(int64_t int64Val) = 0;
    virtual bool NeedWriteJson(std::string strVal) = 0;
    virtual bool NeedWriteJson(double strVal) = 0;
```

**Error1:**
error: call to member function 'NeedWriteJson' is ambiguous
            return toJsonController->NeedWriteJson(llongVal);

---

**Error 2:**

```
 error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<std::string>' (aka 'vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >')
    vec2(ptr ? std::vector<std::string>((char*)ptr, (char*)ptr + size) : std::vector<std::string>())  {
               ^                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:518:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to 'std::__ndk1::vector<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > > >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
    vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __x);
    ^
```

Comment: Just a guess for Error1: `llongVal` is not an exact match for overload parameter types and there is more than 1 valid conversion.  The ambiguous call error message usually continues to list the candidate functions and also the calling parameter type(s).  If possible can you add this information to the question.

Comment: are you possibly linking libraries build with a different ndk version?